# urxvt bitmap fonts are distorted

Tags: fonts, rxvt

I can't seem to get bitmap fonts to render correctly in urxvt terminal.
The fonts look skinny and short, making them distorted and unreadable.

[image: screenshot]

[full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMbZp.jpg)

I'm not sure what is causing it, 
I've done all I can with urxvt I am starting to think is it an X windows related issue, and it's trying to do something strange to my bitmap fonts.

The .Xresources file has the following in regards to fonts

```
urxvt.font:   -gbdfed-creep-regular-r-normal--0-0-96-96-m-0-iso10646-1
urxvt.boldFont:   -gbdfed-creep-regular-r-normal--0-0-96-96-m-0-iso10646-1
```

but the screenshot is taken while running from another terminal:

```
 urxvt -fn '-misc-orp-bold-r-semicondensed--0-0-75-75-c-0-iso10646-1'
```

I've tried nearly all families of my bitfonts that I have, bold, condensed and normal, etc. all the same effect as shown. What should I do?

Comment: Is it just in Urxvt, or in all terminal emulators?

Comment: Seems to be. I tried setting a few in gnome terminal. They worked but were a bit sub optimal. Definitely not to the level of this though,

Comment: Does your distro disable them by default? Check in `/etc/fonts/conf.d` or wherever system font settings are stored.

Comment: Yeah forgot to mention that yes it did but iremoved it, and added the usebitmap fonts option. No luck with either

Comment: I can't edit my comment above but it may seem confusing, it would be better to say that yes the bitmap fonts show fine in gnome terminal. When I said sub optimal I mean i think its trying to antialias them and stuff, but they display fine. and also when I said I tried and no luck with either I mean I lauched urxvt with and without the use bitmap fonts option added in fonts/conf.d

Comment: I also have urxvt bitmap font rendering problem on Fedora 21 and 22 but not on Fedora 20 -- and the problem seems to be with X as opening urxvt from Fedora 22 to Fedora 20 X Deskto there is no problem but doing that vice versa (urxvt from F20 to F22 desktop) the same problem appears.